# Qt 4.7.4 C++ QScrollBar -- Use QStyle to Set Size of Slider

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have tried several things to get QScrollBar's slider to change size based on the number of singleSteps(). I would like the stepSize() to be ~1.

The following link has got me the closest, but I can't seem to get it to work.

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/2133-QScrollBar-custom-slider-s-size

What do I need to do to get the slider size to change? I would post code, however like I said above I have tried many different attempts, I would like to clean off my slate and just see a nice clean example of how to change the slider size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the size of the slider is supposed to represent the size of the visible part of the scrolled content. That's what `QAbstractSlider`'s API was designed to do.

If you want to lock the size of the visible part to be some integer multiple of a non-integer overall size of the content, then the idiomatic way to approach it is to rescale the output of the scrollbar by a non-integer factor `height / (maximum() + pageStep())`. The logical height (length) of the document maps to `maximum() + pageStep()`. You can of course set `singleStep()` to be equal to `pageStep()`.

Given some `numStrips` and `height`, proceed as follows:

```
int numStrips;
qreal height;

int page = qRound(height/numStrips);
int max = (numStrips - 1) * page;

scrollBar->setMinimum(0);
scrollBar->setMaximum(max);
scrollBar->setPageStep(page);
scrollBar->setSingleStep(page);

qreal strip = scrollBar->value() * height / max;
```

Comment: My use case is this. I have a strip chart where you can add or remove strips from a chart. The strips are rendered in their own glViewports() within a GLWidget. I override QScrollBar's behavior, such that the number of scrolls equals the number of strips. That is the singleStep() is set to #ofStrips/mHeight. This leads to round off error. I need to try and eliminate some of this by dynamically sizing the slider.

Comment: This is my workaround for Qt using and integer value for their stepsize.

Comment: The other issue with my method is that, if #ofStrips/mHeight < 1, then the singleStep() gets rounded down to 0. How does your method deal with this issue?

Comment: Use the inverse: `mHeight/#ofStrips`, not the other way around. See the edit.

Comment: A better solution to my Use Case ended up begin, setting min to 0, and max to #OfStrips, and then leaving steps size a constant of 1. Works like a charm.

Comment: If you want to scroll by one strip at a time -- that's the obvious thing to do. I didn't realize that's what you wanted. That's the problem with questions that begin with a solution without explaining what the problem is.